# Going over the API limit in Shopify?

Tags: shopify

I need a maximum of 250 products with one API call. How can I archive this?
Unfortunately I have no experience in Ruby. Maybe someone can wise me a direction.

Thank you,

Comment: I recommend you to explain it more extensively. It's not like people is going to understand your problem with this single line, even less if they haven't worked with the API. Besides it, you sould show what have you tried and what is exactly what you can't achieve.

Answer (score 2):

If you need 250 items as you asked, which is the limit. You just need to add an extra parameter to your request. It defaults to 50 if *limit* doesn't present. It should do the trick.

```
/admin/products.json?limit=250
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot increase the limit beyond 250 per page. Nevertheless use this `page` parameter to get the next 250 products. I'm not aware of ruby but this is the logical flow:

1. GET url = `/admin/products.json?limit=250&page={{p}}`
2. Assign value of `p` as `1`
3. Start calling API. For each successful return increase value of `p`
4. Check if GET returns less than `250` items. If yes, continue to next step, else go to step 3
5. Exit